# Match string in file and delete that line

Tags: php, file

Hello all I am trying to delete a particular record.  The user enters a value and I'm trying to delete that record from the existing file:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="get">
    Id:<br> <input type="text" name="id">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
   $handle = fopen("Customer1.txt","r");

   while (!feof($handle) ) {
       $line = fgets($handle);
       $a = explode('|',$line); 
       //print_r($a);      

       if(isset($_GET['id']) == $a[0]); {
           $remove = array_shift($a);
           print_r($remove);
       }
       //echo "$a[0]<br>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: You should write the **main text** in the actual question body - **not** in the title! The title should be short and sweet and give some relevant context only

Comment: `isset(ANYTHING)` returns a boolean, either TRUE or FALSE

Comment: IF does not have a `;` after the test so `if(isset($_GET['id']) == $a[0]);` is not good

Comment: You are not rewriting anything to the file, it will remain exectly as you found it

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

`isset` returns `true` or `false` and will always `==` a non-empty value, `array_shift` only removes the first element of the array that you created from the line and you never write the file.

Just check each line and if it doesn't contain the value add it to a result array and write that array to the file:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
   while (!feof($handle) ) {
       $line = fgets($handle);
       $a = explode('|', $line); 

       if($_GET['id'] != $a[0]) { // add lines to result if they don't contain
            $results[] = $line;
       }
   }
}
file_put_contents("Customer1.txt", $results);
```

However if the file is not huge, just read the lines into an array and filter out what contains the `$_GET["id"]`:

```
$lines = file("Customer1.txt");
$lines = array_filter($lines, function($v) { return explode("|", $v)[0] != $_GET["id"]; });
file_put_contents("Customer1.txt", $lines);
```